# Hibernate_sequence does not exist with hibernate envers

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate Envers with entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "core")
@Audited public class Users implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<Users> {
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1250157348010696249L;    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "userid")
    protected Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "aduserid")
    protected String aduserId;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    protected String firstName;

    @Column(name = "middlename")
```

i am getting error hibernate sequence does not exist .

when i am changing false
then it says revision generator does not exist.
Pls help me.

Comment: Please format your question properbly

Comment: Use a hbm2ddl export, create the script and check the `CREATE` statements have been run on your database.  Maybe just use the script as-is in a fresh empty database ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do ... you probably need the hibernate_sequence table that will get created in the script if it is needed.  What database you use?

Comment: Was the issue identified? Could you please post your fix? I am evaluating using hibernate-envers and having this same issue when I add the @Audited annotation to the entity class.

Answer (score 13):

you need to create `hibernate_sequence` in your database,
check sample code

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence  INCREMENT 1  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

Comment: Is this the case with every DB ? I remember using envers with an SQL Server DB and there I created no explicit sequence (or I am not able to find it in the project's code).

Comment: It worked. But I couldn't find any documentation indicating that we must create this sequence. Also, even if we set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create`, hibernate won't generate the sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate Envers expects a global sequence "hibernate_sequence" in order to insert into the "revinfo" table.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a custom entity for the revision info:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity
@Table(name="_revinfo")
public class RevInfoEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @RevisionNumber
    @Column(name="rev")
    private long rev;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    @Column(name="revtstmp")
    private LocalDateTime revtstmp;
}
```

The table and column names maybe have to be adjusted.